# How to retrieve the address book content?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, addressbook

I want to ask an question about the objective C iPhone application. In my application, I would like to retrieve the content of the  (e,g name, phone, email address) in to my application. But I have no idea about what I need to do? Can anyone provide some information, library or link for my to study? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the AddressBook.framework and/or the AddressBookUI.framework. See the [Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH1-SW1) for assistance. With these frameworks imported you can display an `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` to retrieve an contact object for example.

Hope that helps
–f